# Ansible - execute conditionaly if item in loop

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to execute a shell command only once if one of the element I'm looping on contains a property.

vars ex:

```
 myinventory:
 - group
   listitems:
   - List_item1
     execute_command: true
   - List_item2
...
```

Task example:

```
- name: cookbook | dostuff
  loop: "{{ group|subelements('listitems') }}"
  shell: install a package when one of the listems contains execute_command == true
  when: >
    (
    (
    item.1 is defined
    ) and
<I don't know>
    )
```

Comment: You want to loop over the `listitems` and execute a shell command on the first occurence of `execute_command` and exit?

Comment: Yes, for example :-). In other language, like java, it's called 'findAny()'

Comment: To confirm, Can it proceed with looping to check if any other item in the list still has `execute_command`?

Comment: Illustrating it with arrays: [1,2,3,4,5].dostuff(2) => execute. [1,2,2,4,5].dostuff(2) => execute. [1,3,3,4,5].dostuff(2) => do not execute.

Comment: How many times do you want to execute for the second array you have shown above? Or, Let us say List_item1 and List_item3 has `execute_command : true`, what would be your expected outcome?

Comment: I want to execute the command only once, no matter the amount of match

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful if you would fix the `- group` in your example to be legal yaml, since we can't _guess_ what structure you are trying to describe; having said that, the answer to your question is almost certainly [`selectattr("execute_command")`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#selectattr) and [`| first`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#first) in some combination